# One's a question about cars only, and the other's a question about all vehicles (SR4) - should the latter be closed as a duplicate of the former?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions, closing, reopen

I'm talking about this question of mine for SR4: "[What are the fastest vehicles, and where or how can I get them?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/146007/4797)" - which was closed* as a duplicate of: "[What is the fastest car in Saints Row 4, and where can I find it?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/128279/4797)"

In the latter question, OP asked about the fastest cars only (usually defined as a four-wheeled vehicle that runs on roads). I feel that editing that question to broaden it to include all vehicles might change too much of what OP intended with their question.

The reason I made my own question and self-answer about all vehicles is so that the answer will cover non-car vehicles too, like aircraft and motorcycles. I [commented something to the same effect](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/146007/what-are-the-fastest-vehicles-and-where-or-how-can-i-get-them#comment197481_146007) on the question while it was getting close votes but none of the close voters replied.

Note that the [Reopen review of my question has been completed](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/63324), which is one of the reasons I posted here.

---

<sup>* and was also ruthlessly downvoted to [oblivion](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oblivion), but that's another topic =)</sup>

Comment: I feel like it's a problem of making the original question too narrow.

Comment: Even if the questions are not the same, the answers could be. Your answer to the second question covers your own question, as well -- "go look at the wiki and you can sort it as you like for any particular criteria". So I can see the view of the close-voters.

Comment: @TZHX Similar answers in different questions does not mean that one of the questions is a duplicate of the other. "*go look at the wiki and you can sort it as you like…*" In the SR wiki link I put as a source, you'll notice that the info on where the cars can be found or how they are obtained are not all there, only the list of vehicles and their speeds are from there. It is I who collated and put the info about where or how to obtain the vehicles in my answer. So the view that my answer is a simple copy-paste from a wiki article is incorrect. I also don't think it's a valid close vote reason.

Comment: @galacticninja That's nice.

Comment: Related: [Is a question a duplicate just because it asks for something that can be part of another question's answer?](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7359/is-a-question-a-duplicate-just-because-it-asks-for-something-that-can-be-part-of)